# parse $_SERVER['argv'] into a single array, best method?

Tags: php

I need to parse the $_SERVER['argv'] array into a single array.

I can decide how to get the parameters.

So for example the script was called like this: `php script.php name:jack operation:full`

I get the parameters in $_SERVER['argv'] like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => script.php
    [1] => name:jack
    [2] => operation:full_res
)
```

How can I easily move those parameters into one array that would be like this:

$param :

```
Array(['name'] => jack ['operation'] => full_res)
```

Comment: Is this for CLI arg processing?  In that case `$argv` is probably better, no?

Comment: not according to these guys: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393949/system-function-call-any-suggestions/9393989#comment11913469_9393989

Comment: I've never once used `$_SERERR['argv']` nor seen it mentioned on the php-general list in several years of active posting.  The mentality of _always user superglobals_, I can't advocate; from my perspective that is the unorthodox approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for [`getopt`](http://www.php.net/getopt), although it would alter the format of your arguments somewhat.

```
<?php
var_dump(getopt('',array('name::','operation::')));
?>
```

From the command line:

```
$ php opt.php --name=foo --operation=bar
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  ["operation"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people like my utility function for PHP CLI arguments:

```
<?php
/**
 * parseArgs Command Line Interface (CLI) utility function.
 * @usage               $args = parseArgs($_SERVER['argv']);
 * @author              Patrick Fisher <patrick@pwfisher.com>
 * @source              https://github.com/pwfisher/CommandLine.php
 */
function parseArgs($argv = null) {
    $argv = $argv ? $argv : $_SERVER['argv']; array_shift($argv); $o = array();
    foreach ($argv as $a) {
        if (substr($a, 0, 2) == '--') { $eq = strpos($a, '=');
            if ($eq !== false) { $o[substr($a, 2, $eq - 2)] = substr($a, $eq + 1); }
            else { $k = substr($a, 2); if (!isset($o[$k])) { $o[$k] = true; } } }
        else if (substr($a, 0, 1) == '-') {
            if (substr($a, 2, 1) == '=') { $o[substr($a, 1, 1)] = substr($a, 3); }
            else { foreach (str_split(substr($a, 1)) as $k) { if (!isset($o[$k])) { $o[$k] = true; } } } }
        else { $o[] = $a; } }
    return $o;
}
```

That will do what you ask for and more. See example usage and a helper class at https://github.com/pwfisher/CommandLine.php.

Answer (score 1):

```
$param = array();
foreach($_SERVER['argv'] as $value) {
  if(substr_count($value, ':') !== 1)
    continue;
  $vals = explode(':', $value);
  $param[$vals[0]] = $vals[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array();

$_args = array_slice($_SERVER['argv'], 1);
foreach ($_args as $_arg) {
    $arg = explode(':', $_arg);

    if (count($arg) > 1)
        $args[ $arg[0] ] = $arg[1];
    else
        $args[] = $arg[0];
}
```